# How long does it take for a transaction to confirm?

Tags: iota-network

How long does it take for a transaction to confirm? What is required for this process?

Comment: my bee node is consistently 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Around 7 seconds in the new Chrysalis Network. See here: https://chrysalis.thetangle.org/

Answer (score 0):

According to https://chrysalis.thetangle.org/ the current confirmation time is around 7 seconds. In a pre-Coordicide network this completely depends on the milestone interval which is currently set at 10 seconds but can be changed at anytime by the Coordinator (ie. the IOTA Foundation).